# Distribute compiled fortran library with module files

Tags: fortran

I have a `Fortran` library that uses a lot of modules. I use the `ifort` compiler on Windows. Therefore, I get a `*.lib` file for the library and `*.mod` files for the used modules.

This has the disadvantage that I also have to distribute the `*.mod` files, if I want to use the compiled library in another programme. How can this be prevented? I see two possibilities:

1. Create an interface, where functions are defined that are used to call the functions or procedures inside the library modules. So, I only have to provide the file, where the interface is defined.
2. Use the c-interface and export names for all module functions and procedures that should be used from outside the library using `bind(c)` in function definitions. Then I can distribute the library with a c-like header file.

Are there any other possibilities? What are best practices to distribute a compiled fortran library that uses modules?

Comment: By "distribute", do you mean to other programs of yourself, or to other people?   If to yourself, then you should just be able to place the .mod files on a search path.  If distributing to other people, another solution is to distribute the library in source code form.   Which can be much easier since you don't have to worry about compiler versions.  How necessary is it to you do distribute in compiled form?

Comment: I'm not the owner of the code, so I cannot distribute the source. I have to provide the compiled library to a third party.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that to distribute also the `.mod` file is the easiest, by far, if it supposed to by used called from Fortran. If it is to be called from  other languages, you need the C interface anyway.

The bad thing is loosing the Fortran explicit interfaces. With option number 1 you can probably still have it, if you supply an include file with interface blocks, but just supplying the `.mod` file is better IMHO.

Comment: I didn't know that I loose the explicit interface with the C option. +1!

Comment: I agree that supplying the mod is the best.  Note the options aren't mutually exclusive - you could also provide interface blocks for BIND(C) procedures (in fact... you have to!) - you don't have to lose the explicit interface.  The problem with BIND(C) is that you are *very* restricted in what can be a dummy argument or function result (all arguments must be non-optional and  interoperable, etc).  If interface blocks are provided then it is best that they are provided in a module as source code.